# How to rebuild the string list programmatically (i.e. in IDC and/or IDAPython)?

Tags: ida, idapython, idc

Is there an API which lets me programmatically:

1. set the default string type (<kbd>Setup</kbd>) and
2. rebuild the string list (<kbd>Rebuild</kbd>)

???

[image: Context menu of the string list]

Comment: Older versions of IDA used to use `strwinsetup_t` with `set_strlist_options`, it was deprecated in the 7.0 transition as per https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/7_0/docs/api70_porting_guide/ under strlist.hpp. Usage of it can be found here: https://github.com/arizvisa/ida-minsc/blob/persistence-refactor/base/ui.py#L705. Since then I think it was moved to the registry with the rest of the UI-related stuff (accessed via registry.hpp in the sdk), but since I'm not on that platform I can't check. It's probably under Software/Hex-Rays/IDA or something.

Comment: @AliRizvi-Santiago thanks so much, I'll have a look in the evening.

Answer (score 1):

To rebuild the string list: `ida_strlist.build_strlist()`.

I'm not sure if you can set the default type. `ida_strlist.get_strlist_options()` returns the options, but the return type is `const`.